# Difference between 'online education' and 'distance learning'

Tags: difference

> Is there any difference between '**online education**' and '**distance
>   learning**'

Comment: **[distance learning](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/distance-learning)** has existed even before the age of the Internet.

Comment: Distance learning has various forms, (including online, broadcast or postal). Online education's uniqueness lies on the medium, which is the utilization of the Internet (online platforms and applications).

Comment: Interesting question but I would say that education and learning are quite different terms.

Comment: Brilliant point! It actually reminds me of a book in which the author states that language learning is different from language education in terms of the educational goal.

Answer (score 1):

**"Online education"** involves education over the Internet. This doesn't mean that the teacher and the students are geographically far apart. For all you know, the instructor might still be in the very same room. 
**"Distance education"** means that the teacher and the student are far apart. There is a "distance" factor between them. So yes, they are very different. 
"Distance education" needn't use the Internet either. It can be done via Postal service or through a messenger.